# 勝負 being used with あげる、もらう、くれる

Tags: usage, kanji, english-to-japanese, sentence, japanese-to-english

Is it possible to use 勝負 with あげる、もらう、くれる?
ex. "I'll give you this match." (Give the win)

Also, can 勝負 be used in place of a physical videogame?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's physical videogame? Physical copy of a videogame, or...?

Comment: yeah, because I saw a local use この勝負はあげる. I only know that you can add あげる when it's 勝負してあげる, so I'm confused if he meant it as a physical copy of a videogame.

Comment: 勝負 doesn't really have anything to do with video games though? Except that you can have a match against someone within a game, but you can do basically anything in a video game, so that doesn't narrow it down much.

Comment: ^ not all "game" has to be videogame, right?

Answer (score 1):

In Japan, when you use the word "勝負" with "もらう" it means
この勝負は僕が貰ったね。"I've got this game, haven't I?

Or...この勝負は君にあげるよ。"I'll give you this game."

These phrases are common.

Sure.
この勝負、私にくれる？ "Can I have this game?

It is also common to say.

However, except when you say things like these, you don't say あげる, もらう, くれる the game.

Also, be aware that these expressions are used in casual settings rather than formal ones.
If you are using them for a friend, there is no problem.

Therefore, these expressions cannot be used when the outcome of a game is decided from the standpoint of a third party. This is only for one-on-one conversations.

When "勝負" is used as a noun, it refers only to a match,a game or a confrontation.

My English is not very good, so I don't know if I'm answering your question correctly, but I think these are the only ways to use the word "勝負".
It's a difficult expression, but it would be cool to use!